# PHP API processing inbound JSON from mobile app

Tags: javascript, php, json, rest, post

I am passing data from my app to a new server api I am trying to create.  The data in javascript is formatted using `JSON.stringify(dataObj)` before being sent out.  In the HTTP Headers the data is formatted as follows (taken directly from the XHR Request Payload:

```
[{table: "userTable", task: 1,…},…]
0:{table: "userTable", task: 1,…}
  data:{user_fName: "blah", user_lName: "user", user_phone: "555-1212", user_email: "blahuser@gmail.com",…}
    app_installDate:"Mon Oct 24 2016 11:15:35 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
    app_installTime:"Mon Oct 24 2016 11:15:35 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
    user_address1:""
    user_address2:""
    user_city:""
    user_country:""
    user_email:"blahuser@gmail.com"
    user_fName:"blah"
    user_lName:"user"
    user_phone:"555-1212"
    user_state:""
    user_zip:""
  table:"userTable"
  task:1
1:{table: "userDevice", task: 1, data: {app_installTime: "Mon Oct 24 2016 11:15:35 GMT-0400 (EDT)",…}}
  data:{app_installTime: "Mon Oct 24 2016 11:15:35 GMT-0400 (EDT)",…}
  table:"userDevice"
  task:1
2:{table: "userSettings", task: 1,…}
3:{table: "userSessions", task: 1,…}
```

My test API is responding back to the app with a 200 OK code and I even manually pass back a JSON data set to the app - which the app see's fine.  However, I am having a hard time processing the incoming JSON to the API.  I tried via $_POST, via file_get_contents('php://input') and even json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')).  I am then printing that out to a log file on the server just to see the data structure but I am not getting anything.

```
$newData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')) ;  // even tried just $_POST, but didn't work.
$file = "testfile.log" ;
file_put_contents($file,$newData) ;

foreach ($newData as $dataSet) {
  $pTable = $dataSet["table"] ;
  $pTask = $dataSet["task"] ;
  $pData = $dataSet["data"] ;
  // pData is an object, and I need to get the keyName 
  // and the keyValue of each pair in the object
}
```

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. How can I process the incoming JSON via a loop?  Within that loop I need to extract the keyNames from the subdata in the key value "data" ?

How I am sending data from my app:

```
  for (var x=0;x<dataObj.length;x++) {  // array of objects
    dataObj[x].data = apiVariables(dataObj[x].table) ;  // this updates and retrieves all the table fields that need to be passed to the api.
  }

  var baseUrl = "https://api.foo.com/v1/" ;
  var headers = {'Pragma':'no-cache', Expires: -1, 'Cache-Control':'no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate', Authorization: 'Token ' +clientToken} ;
  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl ,
    headers: headers,
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObj)
  }
  return $http(req).then(function(result) { .... }) ;
```

Comment: SHow how you send the data from javascript

Comment: @RiggsFolly - added the app $http call to the api.

Comment: In the php, when I add `$newData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true) ;` and output $newData to a local file, the file simply says `ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray` - so something is coming across, but still no able to access it.